# Returning a value in list that occurs n times

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner in Python and am trying to figure this out.
For example, if I would like to return the value in a list that occurs len(list)//3+1 times. I wanted to use a for loop in combination with the count and sort method but I'm not sure how exactly to implement that.

```
list.sort()

duplicates=[]
for i in list:
    if list.count(i//3+1):
        if i not in duplicates:
            duplicates.append(i)
```

Comment: Don't use the names of [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), like `list`, as variable names. It shadows the built-in function and can lead to unexpected behavior down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean get items that occurance count equals to some fixed value ( `len(list)//3+1` )?

```py
lst = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
lst.sort()

duplicates = []
for i in lst:
    if lst.count(i) == len(lst) // 3 + 1:
        if i not in duplicates:
            duplicates.append(i)
print(duplicates)
```

*Some ways to improve*

- Use `Set` to keep unique ones automatically
- `lst.count` time complexity is `O(n)`, so better not calculate for each item.
- `Count` is irrelavent of order, so only sort when you need print.

```py
from collections import Counter

lst = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
expected_cnt = len(lst) // 3 + 1
print(f'expected_cnt={expected_cnt}')
ct = Counter(lst)
print(ct)
uniques = set([k for k, v in ct.items() if v == expected_cnt])
print(sorted(list(uniques)))
```

*output*

```sh
expected_cnt=4
Counter({4: 4, 3: 3, 2: 2, 1: 1})
[4]
```

Comment: Actually, I want to just return the number in the list that is appearing at least 3 times.  So if the inputted list was [1,1,2,3,4,1], the output would be 1 since that is the number that appears three times. And it would return None if there was no number that appeared at least three times. Sorry, I should have led with an example to clarify what I meant.

Comment: then you just change the `==` operator to `>=` and hardcode `expected_cnt=3`. the algorithm don't have to change.